# IdentityServer4 Access Token Save in DB

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using identityserver4 with Asp.net Identity. My question is very simple that how can i save my access token in my DB because I have a scenario in which i want to save my access token in DB. Can anyone please guide me how can i do this?

Actually, during debug in db saves nothing (only email and password's hash-code ). I want save access token in db for manage my secure API. For example for bloking specific user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of blocking specific user. do you have any other reasons to save the access_token into database? There is already an way to revoke user access on IdentityServer4

Comment: @MJK I think this is the only reason. What are you talking about? (way to revoke user access on IdentityServer4)

Comment: Have you found your solution?

Comment: @MJK I'm in process now)

Comment: Please mark the question as Answered if you it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of tokens supported

```
namespace IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation
{
  public enum SupportedTokens
  {
    Both,
    Jwt,
    Reference,
  }
}
```

AFIK, If you use the [Reference token](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/), you can revoke the access token or refresh token. Find more details [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/revocation.html)

> You can programmatically revoke tokens using the IdentityModel
>   library:

```
var revocationClient = new TokenRevocationClient(
    RevocationEndpoint,
    "client",
    "secret");

var response = await revocationClient.RevokeAccessTokenAsync(token);
```